# AQuery (Android Query) How to load images actually

Tags: android, caching, gridview, nullpointerexception, android-query

I am currently using [Android Query](https://code.google.com/p/android-query/wiki/ImageLoading) library for image loading from server.

**MAIN PROB:**
I want to store images first time and then after i want to load images from cache.
I have seen here options for [Cache Control](https://code.google.com/p/android-query/wiki/ImageLoading#Cache_Control) using ***memCache*** and ***fileCache*** But i didn't get which is better to use for **slow Internet connection** and minimum **Memory usage**.

I have probably following solution with some confusion:

First of all i have used like this:( *memCache* and *fileCache* both `true`)

```
aq.id(holder.prodImage).image(holder.prodImagePath, true, true, 0, R.drawable.no_image, aq.getCachedImage(R.drawable.no_image), AQuery.FADE_IN);
```

But [Here](https://code.google.com/p/android-query/wiki/ImageLoading#Cache_Control) he has said that `if image is huge, avoid memory caching`

But i got problem while **network is slow and memory is not sufficient**

then after i have tried [Delay Image Loading](https://code.google.com/p/android-query/wiki/ImageLoading#Delay_Image_Loading):

```
if(aq.shouldDelay(position, convertView, parent, holder.prodImagePath)){
    aq.id(holder.prodImage).image(R.drawable.no_image);
} else {
    aq.id(holder.prodImage).progress(view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1)).image(holder.prodImagePath, false, true, 0, 0, null, AQuery.FADE_IN);
}
```

But its throwing `NullPointerException` like following:

```
12-10 12:11:26.492: E/AndroidRuntime(23309): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-10 12:11:26.492: E/AndroidRuntime(23309):    at com.androidquery.util.Common.shouldDelay(Common.java:328)
12-10 12:11:26.492: E/AndroidRuntime(23309):    at com.androidquery.util.Common.shouldDelay(Common.java:340)
12-10 12:11:26.492: E/AndroidRuntime(23309):    at com.androidquery.AbstractAQuery.shouldDelay(AbstractAQuery.java:2389)
12-10 12:11:26.492: E/AndroidRuntime(23309):    at com.salesman.fragments.ProductFragment$MyGridViewAdapter.getView(ProductFragment.java:423)
12-10 12:11:26.492: E/AndroidRuntime(23309):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2477)
12-10 12:11:26.492: E/AndroidRuntime(23309):    at android.widget.GridView.makeAndAddView(GridView.java:1331)
12-10 12:11:26.492: E/AndroidRuntime(23309):    at android.widget.GridView.makeRow(GridView.java:331)
12-10 12:11:26.492: E/AndroidRuntime(23309):    at android.widget.GridView.fillDown(GridView.java:283)
12-10 12:11:26.492: E/AndroidRuntime(23309):    at android.widget.GridView.fillGap(GridView.java:243)
12-10 12:11:26.492: E/AndroidRuntime(23309):    at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:5549)
12-10 12:11:26.492: E/AndroidRuntime(23309):    at android.widget.AbsListView$FlingRunnable.run(AbsListView.java:4693)
```

what can i do and how i used this library for this simple problem

Please give me Solution.

Your Help would be Appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally got the solution with following code:

```
/* Settings of Image */
//set the max number of concurrent network connections, default is 4
AjaxCallback.setNetworkLimit(8);

//set the max number of icons (image width <= 50) to be cached in memory, default is 20
BitmapAjaxCallback.setIconCacheLimit(50);

//set the max number of images (image width > 50) to be cached in memory, default is 20
BitmapAjaxCallback.setCacheLimit(50);

aq = new AQuery(context);

/* Getting Images from Server and stored in cache */
aq.id(holder.prodImageView).progress(convertView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1)).image(holder.prodImagePath, true, true, 0, R.drawable.no_image, null, AQuery.FADE_IN);
```

Comment here if you didn't get and have any problem.

Thanks.

Comment: How can we retrieve an image from cache or check whether it exists in cache with aquery.

Comment: @user2779311  `aq.getCachedImage("your url");`

Return bitmap cached by image requests. Returns null if url is not cached.