# How to set the maximum number of network connections in Retrofit

Tags: retrofit, android-networking, androidhttpclient, aquery

I was going through some AQuery code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20488302/aquery-android-query-how-to-load-images-actually) and found there's a way to modify the number of network connections in AQuery.

Is there a way of doing this in retrofit, and what are the default values for retrofit?

```
/* Settings of Image */
//set the max number of concurrent network connections, default is 4
AjaxCallback.setNetworkLimit(8);

//set the max number of icons (image width <= 50) to be cached in memory, default is 20
BitmapAjaxCallback.setIconCacheLimit(50);

//set the max number of images (image width > 50) to be cached in memory, default is 20
BitmapAjaxCallback.setCacheLimit(50);

aq = new AQuery(context);
```

Answer (score 3):

Default number of connection for instance in Retrofit is somewhat on-demand, i.e new thread is created/reused for each new `Runnable` (connection) that is fed to the `Executor`

You can limit network connection by limiting number of `Thread`. When you build your `RestAdapter` do:

```
restAdapterBuilder.setExecutors(Executors.newCachedThreadPool(numberOfConnections), new MainThreadExecutor());
```

or

```
restAdapterBuilder.setExecutors(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numberOfConnections), new MainThreadExecutor());
```

This is exactly the same what AQuery does to limit the number of connections.

See [Executors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) for more