# limit connections in retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

After following this answer here : [answer how to limit retrofit network calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27617583/how-to-set-the-maximum-number-of-network-connections-in-retrofit)

I am doing this:

```
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
    .setEndpoint(url)
    .setExecutors(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5),
        new MainThreadExecutor())
    .setClient(new OkClient())
    .build();
```

To test that this is working, i run a for loop, from 0 to 1000, where in each iteration i fire a request.
However, instead of only 5 requests being sent at every given moment, the app fires all 1000 of them at the same time. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `the app fires all 1000 of them at the same time` - how did you check it?

Comment: thanks for the reply.
I'm using charles, a network sniffer, i can see it's firing all of them at the same time

Comment: It is not because retrofit fires all the 1000 requests that means there is 1000 connections.

Comment: Dimitri, isn't the line 
    Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5)
supposed to make sure that there are no more than 5 "connections", that's what I understood is supposed to happen. thank you in advance